# Muxing large video(100 Mb) file and audio file in Xuggler

Tags: xuggler, xuggle

I am muxing video and audio together using xuggler. Since the video file is large (100 mb) I am getting "java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: out of native memory". I increased the heap size as well, but still getting the same error

Also I added the JNIMemoryModel before the operation begins.

```
JNIMemoryManager.setMemoryModel(MemoryModel.JAVA_STANDARD_HEAP);
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able solve this issue in  a different way. I was getting this issue, not sure what was the reason, when I was combing mp4 and .wav file using "JCodec" and Xuggler framework.

Now I stopped using JCodec and used xuggler only and this issue is not happening any more!!

Thanks